# Upsample data with mean

Tags: datetime, mean, resampling

I am trying to upsample my datetime data and fill in the gap with a mean rather than forward or backward fill.

Sample df-

```
TIME       VALUE
01:00        4
02:00        8       
03:00        2
```

desired output-

```
TIME       VALUE
01:00        4
01:30        6
02:00        8
02:30        5       
03:00        2
```

Currently I did a straightforward resample('30min') and want fill the NaN values

```
TIME       VALUE
01:00        4
01:30       NaN
02:00        8
02:30       NaN       
03:00        2
```

With the mean rather than backward or forward fill.

Answer (score 0):

Figured one way to solve the problem.

```
df2=df.resample('30min',on='Time')
final=df2.interpolate(method='linear')
```

But I would keen to look at other ways to this apart from interpolation!